# How to pass array of char arrays to function by reference?

Tags: arrays, c

I want to initialize array of char arrays in a function:

```
void myFunction(char*** words)
{
   int size = 3;
   char** words_ = (char**) malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
   for (int i=0; i< size; ++i)
   {
       // init each word words[i] with some value
   }
   *words = words_;
}
```

which I use in that way:

```
char** multiple_words;
myFunction(&multiple_words);
```

Is there any other way to write this code better/simpler?
(This code works BTW).

Comment: `char** multiple_words;` is a pointer to pointer to char, not array of array of char. I think you mix up arrays and pointers (this is a common mistake). `char **` also works for pointer to array of pointer to char and pointer to array of pointer to array of char, since a pointer does not know if he points to a single instance or an array (for array with a single dimension).

Answer (score 1):

```
char** myFunction()
{
   int size = 3;
   char** words_ = (char**) malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
   for (int i=0; i< size; ++i)
   {
       // init each word words[i] with some value
   }
   return words_;
}
char **words = myFunction();
```

Comment: I thought about it. It looks better of course, but if I want to have multiple arguments like that in the function, this answer does not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the `malloc` call itself a bit.  You don't need to cast the result of `malloc` in C<sup>1</sup>, so that call could be simplified to

```
char** words_ = malloc(size * sizeof *words);  // sizeof *words == sizeof (char *)
```

*Always* check the result of a `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` call.  Even though the likelihood of the request failing is small, it's not zero.

The `words_` variable really serves no purpose, and at first glance looked like you were redeclaring the `words` function argument.  It would be simpler to get rid of it entirely and just write

```
*words = malloc( sizeof **words * size ); // sizeof **words == sizeof (char *)
```

leaving us with

```
void myFunction(char*** words)
{
   int size = 3;
   *words = malloc(size * sizeof **words);
   if ( *words )
   {
     for (int i=0; i< size; ++i)
     {
         // init each word words[i] with some value
     }
   }
}
```

---

1. At least as of the 1989 standard - if you're using an ancient K&R-era implementation or if you're compiling this code as C++, then a cast is required.  However, if you're writing C++, then you shouldn't be using `malloc` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would create abstractions depending on what I want to represent:

```
struct word {
   char *letters;
};
struct sentence {
   struct word *words;
};

// and then work with those abstractions:

int sentence_create(struct sentence *s) {
    const size_t size = 3;
    s->words = malloc(size * sizeof(*s->words));
    if (s->words == NULL) goto ERR_WORDS;

    s->words[0] = strdup("hello");
    if (s->words[0] == NULL) goto ERR_0;
    s->words[1] = strdup("world");
    if (s->words[1] == NULL) goto ERR_1;
    s->words[2] = NULL;

    // success
    return 0;

    // goto error handling
    free(s->words[1]);
    ERR_1:
    free(s->words[0]);
    ERR_0:
    free(s->words);
    s->words = NULL;
    ERR_WORDS:
    return -ENOMEM;
}

int main() {
    struct sentence sentence;
    if (sentence_create(&sentence) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oh no!");
        abort();
    }
    // TODO: sentence_destroy(&sentence) to free memory
}
```

Also see [wiki.c2 Three Star Programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 100% whether it is easier or not:

```
typedef struct {
    char **words;
} WordList;

void myFunc(WordList *wordList) {
    ...
    wordList->words = malloc(numberOfWords * sizeof(char *));
    // strSource : this string comes from somewhere in your code
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) {
        int numberOfChars = strlen(strSource);
        (wordList->words)[i] = malloc((numberOfChars + 1) * sizeof(char));
        (wordList->words)[i][numberOfChars] = '\0';
        ...
        strcpy((wordList->words)[i], strSource)
        ...
    }
    ...
}

int main() {
    WordList wordList;
    ...
    myFunc(&wordList);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna get icky no matter how you write it.

- A `char**` is fine to use for pointing at the first item in an array of `char*`, each pointing at a string of individual length.
- It is best if the function can `return` a `char**`, but if that isn't possible, then...
- We'd have to return a `char**` through parameters, means we have to write `char***`. Three levels of indirection is always questionable, but this specific case is about the only valid use for it. Or the lesser evil at least, since...
- Some makeshift struct wrapper that does nothing but hiding away the `***` isn't making the code any better or more readable. That's very similar to hiding pointers behind `typedef`, not recommended.

The least messy way to write that might be something like this:

```
void heard (char*** word, size_t size)
{
   char** the_word = malloc( sizeof(char*[size]) );
   
   for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
     const char* str = "bird";          // some random data from somewhere
     the_word[i] = malloc (sizeof str); // allocate room for individual strings
     strcpy(the_word[i], str);
   }

   *word = the_word;
}
```

Then call it as:

```
char** word;
heard(&word, 3);

for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  puts(word[i]);
}
```

The most proper solution is probably to use a complete string container class which handles all of this for you. Then you'd just declare arrays of strings and don't worry about all the details of allocating things manually.